# Create a column with values based on the value of the next row of another column

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below which has one column and I want to create  a second column in which in every row will be placed the value of the next row of the 1st column and in the last row the value of the 1st row of the 1st column . The numbers of rows may differ every time. So the

```
name
1     Alice
2       Bob
3     Cecil
4     David
5 Esmeralda
```

will give

```
name        to
1     Alice       Bob
2       Bob     Cecil
3     Cecil     David
4     David Esmeralda
5 Esmeralda     Alice
```

my code:

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"))



actors$to<-for(i in 1:nrow(actors)){
  actors[i+1,1]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lead` in `dplyr` to get next value :

```
library(dplyr)
actors %>% mutate(to = lead(name, default = first(name)))

#      name        to
#1     Alice       Bob
#2       Bob     Cecil
#3     Cecil     David
#4     David Esmeralda
#5 Esmeralda     Alice
```

`shift` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(actors)[, to := shift(name, type = 'lead', fill = first(name))]
```

and in base R :

```
transform(actors, to = c(name[-1], name[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```r
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"))

library(dplyr)


actors2 <- actors %>% 
  mutate(
    to = lead(name)
  )

curr.pos <- which(is.na(actors2$to))[[1]]
actors2$to[c(curr.pos)] <- actors2$name[1]


#>        name        to
#> 1     Alice       Bob
#> 2       Bob     Cecil
#> 3     Cecil     David
#> 4     David Esmeralda
#> 5 Esmeralda     Alice
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>